# getting Public key of a secure website

Tags: https, public-key-encryption

Other than using browser,How can I get the public key of a websites which use https protocol ?
Are there other ways ? Like from the terminal.

Update - i want all the ways so that i can choose what fits best for me

Comment: You need be more precise. There are multiple dozen ways to get a certificat. From a shell, programmatically, manually or from n clients etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443
```

Certificate is between -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: where to enter the domain name ?

Answer (score 1):

Is [this OpenSSL command](http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#cert-retrieve) what you are looking for?

`openssl s_client -connect ${REMHOST}:${REMPORT}`